# Is there a way to choose where the Komito Analytics events get sent to?

Tags: google-analytics, komito-analytics

Is there any way to specify which Google Analytics account you want to use or how to negate the others?
I have two Google Analytics codes running and would like to test Komito Analytics on only one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Komito will track into all available trackers (which is amazing), but you can use `trackingIds` property which allows you to override this with specific trackers by using one of the following options:

```js
var _komito = _komito || {
  ...
  'trackingIds': 'UA-12345678-1',
  // OR
  'trackingIds': ['UA-12345678-1'],
  // OR
  'trackingIds': ['UA-12345678-1', 'UA-12345678-2', ...]
  ...
};
```

Comment: Even more awesome. Thanks for the quick response. It worked!